# Android Option menu Items icon not showing for release APK

Tags: java, android, kotlin, popupmenu

menu item not showing the item icon in the release mode of the apk and its appearance in the debug mode
here is the snapshot of the XML menu code
**R.menu.menu_more_options**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_share"
            android:title="@string/share" />
    
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_delete"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_delete"
            android:title="@string/delete" />
    
    </menu>
```

and the code for inflating it

```
 val wrapper: Context = ContextThemeWrapper(mActivity, R.style.PopupMenu)
            val popupMenu = PopupMenu(wrapper, view)
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_more_options)
            popupMenu.gravity = Gravity.END
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item: MenuItem ->
                when (item.itemId) {
                    R.id.action_share -> {
                        //TODO rename
                    }
                    R.id.action_delete -> {
                        //TODO delete 
                    }
                   
                    else -> {
                    }
                }
                true
            }
            popupMenu.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the actual question here ?

Comment: the icons in the option menu not showing!

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        var m: Method = popupMenu.menu.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType)
        m.isAccessible = true
        m.invoke(popupMenu.menu, true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

after a deep search, I managed to resolve by adding the upper lines before showing the popup. the full code as below.

```
val wrapper: Context = ContextThemeWrapper(mActivity, R.style.PopupMenu)
    val popupMenu = PopupMenu(wrapper, view)
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_more_options)
    popupMenu.gravity = Gravity.END
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item: MenuItem ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_share -> {
                //TODO rename
            }
            R.id.action_delete -> {
                //TODO delete 
            }

            else -> {
            }
        }
        true
    }

    try {
        var m: Method = popupMenu.menu.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType)
        m.isAccessible = true
        m.invoke(popupMenu.menu, true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    popupMenu.show()
```

hope this helps